# How to sorting repository entity with pagination in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, sorting, pagination, spring-data

I am writing an REST API with Spring Boot.Here,I am trying to sort the list using the 'PagingAndSortingRepository'.This is what I have tried
Method in my Controller class

```
@GetMapping public ResponseEntity
<PagedModel<ComplainDTO>> getComplains(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0",value = "page",required =false)int page, @RequestParam(value="sortBy" ,required = false,defaultValue = "complainId") String sortBy, PagedResourcesAssembler assembler) { 
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
     .body(assembler.toModel(complainService.getAllComplains(page,sortBy)));
  }
```

Method on my service

```
@Override
    public Page<ComplainDTO> getAllComplains(int page,String sortBy) {

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page,20, Sort.by(sortBy));
        Page<ComplainEntity> result =complainRepository.findAll(pageable);
        return result.map(complainEntity -> toDTO(complainEntity));
    }
```

I am taking input from the consumer to sort the list based on given attribute however the default behavior of Sort is Ascending .So,how can I implement this taking user params whether it being ascending or descending aside from using if-else.

Comment: Why you don't use `pageable` in contoller it auto  add request param for api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one option is asking the user to provide the sorting order using `@RequestParam`

```
 @GetMapping public ResponseEntity
<PagedModel<ComplainDTO>> getComplains(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0",value = "page",required =false)int page, 
        @RequestParam(value="sortBy" ,required = false,defaultValue = "complainId") String sortBy, 
        @RequestParam(value="orderBy" ,required = false,defaultValue = "ASC") String orderBy, PagedResourcesAssembler assembler) { 

return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
 .body(assembler.toModel(complainService.getAllComplains(page,sortBy,orderBy)));

}
```

And then in the service pass the sorting order to `Sort` method

```
@Override
public Page<ComplainDTO> getAllComplains(int page,String sortBy, String orderBy) {

    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page,20, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.valueOf(orderBy),sortBy));
    Page<ComplainEntity> result =complainRepository.findAll(pageable);
    return result.map(complainEntity -> toDTO(complainEntity));
}
```